Can a Kerr black hole become super-extremal?
Let's assume there is a large Kerr black hole, which is almost
extremal and would become extremal with the addition of a small
amount of mass $M$ with spin $J$ to make the final $J=M$.
What if this amount of mass $M$ with spin $J$ approached the black hole
simultaneously from opposite sides. One side of the black hole
wouldn't instantly be aware of what was going on at the other side.
Would the black hole temporarily become super-extremal and then
somehow get rid of the excess $J/M$ or would it just partially absorb
mass and spin from each side?

TLDR; No, it cannot.
The answer to this question has a somewhat storied history.
Back in 1974 Wald considered a Gedanken experiment of what would happen if you would try to drop an object into a Kerr black hole that is at the extremal limit. He was able to prove that there are simply no geodesics that enter the black hole with sufficient J/E ratio to push the black hole past the extremal limit. This highlights the main physical obstacle to trying to "overspin" a Kerr black hole, to overspin you need to add mass with loads of angular momentum, but the centrifugal effect from the angular momentum makes it hard for the mass to enter the black hole.
Decades later, in 2009, Jacobson and Sotiriou considered the case closer to that of the OP. Starting from a nearly extremal Kerr black hole they showed that there is a small sliver of parameter space where geodesics entering the black hole have sufficient J/E ratio that they could seemingly push it past the extremal limit and overspin it. I say seemingly, because this analysis neglected the gravitational effects of the body falling into the black hole, the so-called gravitational self-force, which at the time nobody knew how to calculate.
A few years later in 2015 self-force calculations had made breakthrough allowing calculation of the GSF in Kerr spacetime. Using this new technology, Colleoni et al. showed in two papers that the effect of the GSF was just big enough to completely close this sliver of parameter space that would allow overspinning.
This answered the question for trying to overspin a Kerr black hole with a single particle/object. One might wonder (like the OP) of more general matter configurations could evade this result. Two years later Sorce and Wald came back and completely closed off this potential loop hole by showing no distribution of matter satisfying the null energy condition could ever overspin a black hole.*
Both results are marginal in the sense they exclude the possibility of overspinning, but do not exclude the possibility reaching extremality. Even the latter is expected to be impossible by the conjectured third law of black hole mechanics. However, technically, the also leave open the possibility that if one considers higher order corrections (e.g. the second order self-force) these would reopen the possibility of overspinning.
*Note both of Wald's proof's are more general and actually apply to general case of trying to push a Kerr-Newman black hole past extremality by adding charge and/or angular momentum. However, since the OP asked about Kerr I've limited this answer to just the Kerr case. For context it is fair to point out that the Jacobson and Sotiriou paper followed a longer discussion of overcharging nearly extremal Reissner-Nordström black holes initiated in a 1999 paper by Hubeny.

I agree that no matter configuration can make a Kerr black hole
super-extremal, but I would be interested to know more about the
behavior of simultaneously entering particles.  The Sorce
and Wald paper doesn't look at the trajectories.  For example if a
Kerr black hole would become extremal with the addition of 1.5 *
J/M, what if 1.0 * J/M approached simultaneously from each side?
Would it absorb 0.75 * J/M from each side?

@Andrew Each of those particles would need to have a sufficient $J/E$ ratio. The whole point of the GSF answer is that no such trajectories exist. (There is a potential loop hole there in that interaction of the gravitational fields of both particles could conspire to open up a window for overspinning. This loop hole is covered by the Sorce and Wald proof,)
